# Angular Conditionally change background color of element

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I have recently made a new project in Angular 6, and all my previous experience is in Angular 1.5.

I would like to control the background color of an item in my HTML page, based on its text value.

- VALID: Green
- PAUSED: Orange
- INVALID: Red

Is there a way to do this specifically with Angular methods like `ngStyle` or something, rather than just writing a jQuery function in the component to change the CSS class based on the value?

```
<span class="producerState">{{prod.producerState}}</span>
```

Change background of `.producerState` span based on the textual value.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle  Angular has docs you can reference, eh?

Comment: https://v6.angular.io/api/common/NgStyle  specific for v6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you should never use JQuery and Angular together.

and you can use  ngStyle

```
[ngStyle]="yourText=='INVALID'?{'background-color':'red'} : {'background-color': 'white'}"
```

or ngClass

```
[ngClass]="{'invalidClass': yourText=='INVALID'}">
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a variable in the component to hold the css style, and reference it in the turnery operator. But, is there a more concise way of writing the `[ngStyle]` so im not left with `[ngStyle]="myObj"=='INVALID' ? {} : {}, ... 'PAUSED' ... 'VALID'` ?

Comment: my advice is to create a small method, that use switch case to check the current status, and returning the desired style as an output

Comment: `[style.background-color]="yourText == 'INVALID' ? 'red' : 'blue'"` is a shorter way of  writing that first version.